# Prints more than 1 user

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

So when I use my code it prints more than 1 of the users from my DB.

I only want to get one user printed, I tried to do everything I knew about fetching objects.

Could anyone help me?

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM cms_users ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100");
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
echo '
            <aside id="right">
                <div id="main_sep"></div>
  <div id="content_ajax"><article>
<h1 class="top">User panel</h1>
<section class="body">
 <section id="ucp_top">
 <a href="http://causticwow.net/home2/ucp/avatar" id="ucp_avatar">
    <div>Change avatar</div>
</a>

<section id="ucp_info">

    <aside>

        <table width="100%">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td width="10%"><img src="images/icons/user.png"></td>
                <td width="40%">Nickname</td>
                <td width="50%">
                    <a href="http://causticwow.net/home2/ucp/settings" data-tip="Change nickname" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;"><img src="images/icons/pencil.png" align="absbottom"></a>
                    <a href="profile/1989" data-tip="View profile"> '.$row->Nickname.'   </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="10%"><img src="images/icons/world.png"></td>
                <td width="40%">Location</td>
                <td width="50%">
                    <a href="http://causticwow.net/home2/ucp/settings" data-tip="Change location" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;"><img src="images/icons/pencil.png" align="absbottom"></a>
                    '.$row->Location.'
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="10%"><img src="images/icons/plugin.png"></td>
                <td width="40%">Expansion</td>
                <td width="50%">
                    <a href="http://causticwow.net/home2/ucp/expansion" data-tip="Change expansion" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;"><img src="images/icons/cog.png" align="absbottom"></a>
                    '.$row->Expansion.'
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="10%"><img src="images/icons/award_star_bronze_1.png"></td>
                <td width="40%">Account rank</td>
                <td width="50%">'.$row->Rank.'
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </aside>

    <aside>
        <table width="100%">
            <tbody><tr data-tip="Earn voting points by voting for the server">
                <td width="10%"><img src="images/icons/lightning.png"></td>
                <td width="40%">Voting points</td>
                <td width="50%">'.$row->VP.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-tip="Earn donation points by donating money to the server">
                <td width="10%"><img src="images/icons/coins.png"></td>
                <td width="40%">Donation points</td>
                <td width="50%">'.$row->DP.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="10%"><img src="images/icons/shield.png"></td>
                <td width="40%">Account status</td>
                <td width="50%">'.$row->AccStatus.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="10%"><img src="images/icons/date.png"></td>
                <td width="40%">Member since</td>
                <td width="50%">'.$row->created.'</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </aside>
</section>
<div class="clear"></div>   
    </section>

<div class="ucp_divider"></div>
<section id="ucp_buttons">
<a href="http://causticwow.net/home2/vote" style="background-image:url(images/vote_panel.jpg)"></a>

    <a href="http://causticwow.net/home2/donate" style="background-image:url(images/donate_panel.jpg)"></a>

        <a href="http://causticwow.net/home2/store" style="background-image:url(images/item_store.jpg)"></a>

<a href="http://causticwow.net/home2/ucp/settings" style="background-image:url(images/account_settings.jpg)"</a>
<a href="http://causticwow.net/home2/ucp/expansion" style="background-image:url(images/change_expansion.jpg)"></a>

        <a href="http://causticwow.net/home2/teleport" style="background-image:url(images/teleport_hub.jpg)"></a>



<div class="clear"></div>
 </section>

<div class="ucp_divider"></div>

</section>
</article></div>
            </aside>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

                <footer>
<a href="http://raxezdev.com/fusioncms" id="logo" target="_blank"></a>
<p>© Copyright 2014 Admin Frozty</p>
            <p id="design"> <a target="_new" href=""></a></p>
</footer>
'; }
```

When it prints them it first prints one where it is supposed to be then the other one under the footer.

Comment: May I suggest you use a view or simply end your PHP tags and then output the HTML instead of having a huge `echo` statement? That said, why use `LIMIT 100` if you want to show just one? Use `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Here's the code itself. [http://pastebin.com/TLpe2PLN]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SQL statement using mysqli

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM cms_users ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100");
```

gets the first 100 rows from cms_users

If you only want a single row to be outputted, or used, change the LIMIT to 1

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM cms_users ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
```

Also, the while loop you have parses through each row that was found using the conditions you put in the query (in this case, no conditions except output order).

Addendum to your comment below:

If you want to add a parameter - refer to [mysqli.prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) statements.

The query you want to create is something like:

```
 SELECT * FROM cms_users WHERE user_id = ? ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

Where the "?" would be the user_id (in your case - 5).

Comment: Now I need to get so that it will show the right user. But it did work. So like if you're logged in as the user id 5 it will show your stats.

Comment: All I need now is a $_SESSION['id'] to link the user_id to.

Comment: @user3535175 - the variable can be anything you like, including $_SESSION['id']

Comment: When I log in I have this `<?php
require_once('core/config.php');
if(isset($_POST['lSubmit'])) {
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM cms_users");
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
$username = $row->username;
$password = $row->password;
$id = $row->id;
}


if($_POST['username'] == $username && hash("SHA512", $_POST['password']) == $password) {
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
header("Location: index.php");
} else {
header("Location: login.php?fail=true");
alert("Username and/or Password is wrong");
}
} else {
alert("Username and/or Password is wrong");
}`

Answer (score 4):

`LIMIT 100` will return at most 100 rows.

So, if you change to `LIMIT 1` you will get only one result.

Moreover, using a while will iterate through all the results.
If you are sure to have only one row, just do:

```
$row = $result->fetch_object();
```

Answer (score 0):

• If your trouble is that you want only and strictly one result, go with `LIMIT 1` instead of `LIMIT 100`. You can also replace the `while($row = $result->fetch_object())` with a `$row = $result->fetch_object();` because you only have one resulting row.

• If your trouble is that the next user is printed outside the table, then you should:

- First, printing the prepended HTML code, using a echo() before the while
- then echoing one line for each mysql result
- then printing the appended HTML code:

```
// Print the begining HTML code, with opening <tbody> tag
echo('<aside><!--...--><tbody>');

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM cms_users ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100");
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
// print HTML rows for data
echo('<tr><!-- nickname, and others... -->
<!--  ... -->
<a href="profile/1989" data-tip="View profile"> '.$row->Nickname.'</a>
<!--- ... -->
<tr>
     <td width="10%"><img src="images/icons/award_star_bronze_1.png"></td>
     <td width="40%">Account rank</td>
     <td width="50%">'.$row->Rank.'
     </td>
</tr>
');
}
// Print closing tags
echo('
        </tbody></table><!-- ... -->
</footer>');
```

(shortened to make it easier to read).

There, you'll print the table opening tag once, print several rows according to MySQL results, then print the table closing tag once.